# what I need to know to create an animated hover with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, hover

what I need to know to create an animated hover like this in http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/ menu? I know this menu is done with javascript, I have no doubt about where I should look for icons like these.

Comment: f12 look the html when you use mouseover on it and read about Html5, css3 and javascript.

Comment: ok. where i can find the new icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use svg's with css(transition animations)

More you can read here: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

I copied and modified a bit their example with transform:
https://plnkr.co/edit/MHIL0sHMVWQE9lonA4eh?p=preview'

Hope this helps :)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="612px" height="502.174px" viewBox="0 65.326 612 502.174" enable-background="new 0 65.326 612 502.174"
     xml:space="preserve" class="logo">
      <ellipse class="ground" cx="283.5" cy="487.5" rx="259" ry="80"/>
      <path class="kiwi" d="M210.333,65.331C104.367,66.105-12.349,150.637,1.056,276.449c4.303,40.393,18.533,63.704,52.171,79.03
        c36.307,16.544,57.022,54.556,50.406,112.954c-9.935,4.88-17.405,11.031-19.132,20.015c7.531-0.17,14.943-0.312,22.59,4.341
        c20.333,12.375,31.296,27.363,42.979,51.72c1.714,3.572,8.192,2.849,8.312-3.078c0.17-8.467-1.856-17.454-5.226-26.933
        c-2.955-8.313,3.059-7.985,6.917-6.106c6.399,3.115,16.334,9.43,30.39,13.098c5.392,1.407,5.995-3.877,5.224-6.991
        c-1.864-7.522-11.009-10.862-24.519-19.229c-4.82-2.984-0.927-9.736,5.168-8.351l20.234,2.415c3.359,0.763,4.555-6.114,0.882-7.875
        c-14.198-6.804-28.897-10.098-53.864-7.799c-11.617-29.265-29.811-61.617-15.674-81.681c12.639-17.938,31.216-20.74,39.147,43.489
        c-5.002,3.107-11.215,5.031-11.332,13.024c7.201-2.845,11.207-1.399,14.791,0c17.912,6.998,35.462,21.826,52.982,37.309
        c3.739,3.303,8.413-1.718,6.991-6.034c-2.138-6.494-8.053-10.659-14.791-20.016c-3.239-4.495,5.03-7.045,10.886-6.876
        c13.849,0.396,22.886,8.268,35.177,11.218c4.483,1.076,9.741-1.964,6.917-6.917c-3.472-6.085-13.015-9.124-19.18-13.413
        c-4.357-3.029-3.025-7.132,2.697-6.602c3.905,0.361,8.478,2.271,13.908,1.767c9.946-0.925,7.717-7.169-0.883-9.566
        c-19.036-5.304-39.891-6.311-61.665-5.225c-43.837-8.358-31.554-84.887,0-90.363c29.571-5.132,62.966-13.339,99.928-32.156
        c32.668-5.429,64.835-12.446,92.939-33.85c48.106-14.469,111.903,16.113,204.241,149.695c3.926,5.681,15.819,9.94,9.524-6.351
        c-15.893-41.125-68.176-93.328-92.13-132.085c-24.581-39.774-14.34-61.243-39.957-91.247
        c-21.326-24.978-47.502-25.803-77.339-17.365c-23.461,6.634-39.234-7.117-52.98-31.273C318.42,87.525,265.838,64.927,210.333,65.331
        z M445.731,203.01c6.12,0,11.112,4.919,11.112,11.038c0,6.119-4.994,11.111-11.112,11.111s-11.038-4.994-11.038-11.111
        C434.693,207.929,439.613,203.01,445.731,203.01z"/>
      <filter id="pictureFilter" >
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="15" />
      </filter>
    </svg>
  </body>
/html>
```

and the css

```
.kiwi {
      fill: #94d31b; 
      transition: transform 300ms, fill 300ms;
    }
    .kiwi:hover {
      fill: #ace63c; 
      transform: translate(100px,100px)  rotate(30deg);
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    }

    .ground {
      fill: #787f6a;
    }
    .ground:hover {
      filter: url(#pictureFilter);
      fill: #896d3d;
    }
```

Comment: is there a site where has svs icons ready?

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery if I were you, because it looks like those effect are based on jQuery `hover` event:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $('div').hover(
    function(){
     $(this).addClass('active');
    },
    function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');    
    }
  );

})
```

You will need to create CSS class, lets call it 'active', and work on properties of those class

The function like:

```
$('div').animate({left:'+=10px'},500);
```

Can be usefull: {left:'+=10px'} - move section to the left, 500 - milliseconds
I guess it  will create similar effect that you want to achieve

Comment: Why would you use jQuery and not just the css :hover selector?

Comment: As for me Jquerry is more flexible and has more implementations then css, imho

Comment: But in this case, you're just using it to apply a class. You can use css transitions on the :hover selector and you don't need to have javascript at all. This just seems like overkill.

Comment: How would make something like : $('div').animate({left:'+=10px'},500); - (move the section right or left whith delay) in CSS only?

Comment: div { left: 0px; transition: left 500ms; transition-delay: 500ms } div:hover { left: 10px; }

Comment: Looks like you really good in CSS, never heard of this... Is this CSS3?